# How can I ask questions about the terrorist situation in Nigeria and Cameroon on this site?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have multiple questions about the terrorist situation in Nigeria and Cameroon. I had people that were in Iraq before I went so I was able to learn from them, and it was crucial to me surviving for the 18 months I was there.

I am trying to get information on here but I'm new to this and am not 100% on how everything works on here. If anyone knows the right tags and stuff I need to put to get the info I need I would greatly appreciate it.

I'm leaving for Africa pretty soon and trying to prepare myself as much as I can.

Answer (score 3):

Also consider if your questions might be more relevant on other websites of the Stackexchange network.

Politics stackexchange is for asking questions about the *political systems* of countries. We are more concerned about the backgrounds and the big picture.

But when you have questions about how to ensure your personal safety, then most of your questions will likely not be political. The reason *why* you need to be concerned might be political, but you are likely not interested in the reasons but rather in the effects the political circumstances have on you as a foreigner and how you need to behave because of them.

- When you want to know which areas are safe for foreigners and what local customs you need to follow to avoid offending anyone, consider asking on [travel stackexchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com).
- When you have specific questions about local laws, you could try [law stackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com).

Comment: O I  just want to prepare myself..ill be with the coalition o

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're looking for expansion upon a specific concept as executed in those areas, your questions are bound to be either too broad or off topic for the SE model.

What you need is a primer, that will give you an adequate baseline level of knowledge. From that, you could ask specific, on topic, questions that search for expansion on what you've learned.

For that baseline, recommend you review the Department of States or Embassy websites for active concerns about traveling in X area. For instance:
[Nigeria Travel Warning](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/alertswarnings/nigeria-travel-warning.html)
[Nigeria General info](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/nigeria.html)
[US Embassy to Nigeria.](http://nigeria.usembassy.gov/warden_messages.html)